# Mandelbrot set defined by a specific function

Tags: javascript, canvas, pseudocode, fractals, mandelbrot

I'm experimenting with canvas and I'm trying to modify **[this piece of code](http://simpledeveloper.com/mandelbrot/)**, but unfortunately I don't understand some parts of it.

My question is - how to customize the above code to be defined for example by

```
f(z) = c^e(-z)
```

(the formula is taken from a book with fractal examples)?

I know that I need to change this part of code:

```
function computeRow(task) {
    var iter = 0;
    var c_i = task.i;
    var max_iter = task.max_iter;
    var escape = task.escape * task.escape;
    task.values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < task.width; i++) {
        var c_r = task.r_min + (task.r_max - task.r_min) * i / task.width;
        var z_r = 0, z_i = 0;

        for (iter = 0; z_r*z_r + z_i*z_i < escape && iter < max_iter; iter++) {
            // z -> z^2 + c
            var tmp = z_r*z_r - z_i*z_i + c_r;
            z_i = 2 * z_r * z_i + c_i;
            z_r = tmp;
        }
        if (iter == max_iter) {
            iter = -1;
        }
        task.values.push(iter);
    }
    return task;
}
```

But can't what z_i, z_r, c_i, c_r really means and how I could bind them to the above formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: complex number have a two part: real,  imaginary. So `z = z_r + z_i*i`

Comment: sorry but I really don't understand how to implement it. In the code above z=z^2 + c but can't see where and how z exactly is used :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complex number have a two part: real, imaginary.
So `z = a + b*i`, where `a` is real part, and `b*i` is imaginary.
In provided sample for `z=z^2+c`, where `z=z_r+z_i*i`

**NOTE:** `i*i = -1`
So `z^2 = (z_r+z_i*i)*(z_r+z_i*i) = z_r*z_r+2*z_r*z_i*i + z_i*i*z_i*i = z_r*z_r+2*z_r*z_i*i - z_i*z_i`
now add `c`: `z_r*z_r+2*z_r*z_i*i - z_i*z_i + c_r + c_i*i` group it

```
z_r*z_r+2*z_r*z_i*i - z_i*z_i + c_r + c_i*i = (z_r*z_r - z_i*z_i + c_r) + (2*z_r*z_i + c_i)*i
```

So we get `tmp` var from code - is real part of new `z`

```
tmp = z_r*z_r - z_i*z_i + c_r
```

and imaginary part

```
2*z_r*z_i + c_i
```

Since `z = z_r + z_i * i`, we need assign

```
z_r = z_r*z_r - z_i*z_i + c_r
z_i = 2*z_r*z_i + c_i
```

**UPDATE:** for `f(z) = e^z - c`

first, few complex form: `x = a+b*i = |x|(cos(p)+i*sin(p)) = |x|*e^(i*p)`
where `|x| = sqrt(a*a + b*b)` and `p = b/a`

in our case: `p=z_i/z_r`, `|z| = sqrt(z_r*z_r+z_i*z_i)`

```
e^z = e^(z_r+z_i*i) = e^z_r * (e^z_i*i) = e^z_r * (cos(p)+i*sin(p)) = (e^z_r * cos(p)) + i * (e^z_r * sin(p))
```

subtract `c`:

```
(e^z_r * cos(p)) + i * (e^z_r * sin(p)) - c_r - c_i*i = (e^z_r * cos(p) - c_r) + i * (e^z_r * sin(p) - c_i)
```

so *new z*

```
z_r = (e^z_r * cos(p) - c_r) = (e^z_r * cos(z_i/z_r) - c_r)
z_i = (e^z_r * sin(p) - c_i) = (e^z_r * sin(z_i/z_r) - c_i)
```

Comment: Great explanation, now I get it thanks :).
p.s. this tutorial also explain very good what actually the complex plane looks like - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YaYmyfy9Z4

Comment: Could I ask you something more? If I understood right the main idea is to group the expression like A + B*i. But how to proceed when this kind of grouping is not obviously. Take for example the above equation as power of E - e^(z^2 + c)

Comment: @user3845133 it's same: complex number have a few form so you can see about for example here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Forms.aspx

Comment: Sorry, last question I promise - If I understand the article in the above link, the more simple expression e^z - c must be equal to this http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn5065.png, right? (a = z_r, b = z_i, u = c_r, v = c_i)

Comment: @user3845133 i udate answer: possibly you mean different function?

Comment: ah, sorry, I made a typo(z was on sqare), I'm idiot...anyway... Great explanation again, but I couldn't understand why I can't use directly the Euler's formula e^(ix) = cos(x) + i*sin(x). I will understand if you don't answer me anymore...maybe the question is more appropriate for mathoverflow...

Comment: as i now, `x` in `e^(ix)` is **real**, but in your formula `e^z`, `z` is **complex**